# Symbols in Java

Tags: java, symbols

In Java what is exactly a "symbol"? I encountered code like

```
RuleContext.USERNAME
```

described as symbol.
I think of it as a property of the object RuleContext. Isn't it?

In manuals such as "Thinking in Java ed.3" I cannot find "symbol" at all.
Thank you!

Comment: You should provide more information describing the environment of your question. I can only guess that RuleContext.USERNAME is a final static member of the class RuleContext - a constant. In this case it is perfectly okay to call it a symbol since it defines some entity that symbolizes the constant value.

Comment: May be they mean that it is symbolic constant.

Comment: I believe this has to do with being "visible to all". If you have a static final declared as USERCOUNT, it may be called a symbol. In real-time C, we say symbols to those that are in shared memory SCRMNET. The idea is that you do something with a symbol and the change gets fed back to everyone who can see this symbol.

Comment: Just go to RuleContext class, if you have the source code, and check what USERNAME is.

Comment: I can't answer with certainty nor with a valid reference, but I always interpreted the usage of the term "symbol" to come from the lexical analysis phase of designing a compiler. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: I believe here symbol is not a Java-specific thing, rather it is a general concept in compiler construction/formal language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(formal)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a static constant (by convention of capital letters) or if RuleContext is an enumeration type then it could be an enumeration literal (maybe they call it a "symbol").

Answer (score 0):

I found this reply very clear:

Well In Java, a symbol is any variable/ token used in your application. If it cannot be resolved, then you will get an error (...)